# quantity increase/decrease in woocommerce with ajax?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I m using this code to update my cart when i m in CART page-

```
jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change keyup mouseup', 'input.qty', function(){ // keyup and mouseup for Firefox support
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel previously scheduled event
    if (jQuery(this).val() == '') return; //qty empty, instead of removing item from cart, do nothing
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
    }, 1000 );
});
```

I have increase decrease buttons as same as in shop page as well and trying to do same thing with this code

```
jQuery('li.product').on('change keyup mouseup', 'input.qty', function(){ // keyup and mouseup for Firefox support
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel previously scheduled event
    if (jQuery(this).val() == '') return; //qty empty, instead of removing item from cart, do nothing
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
    }, 1000 );
});
```

but its not working, how to solve it ???

Comment: Hi please add HTML code so we can solve it easily

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove disabled property before update cart

jQuery("[name='update_cart']").prop("disabled", false);

So code will be:

jQuery('li.product').on('change keyup mouseup', 'input.qty', function(){ // keyup and mouseup for Firefox support
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel previously scheduled event
    if (jQuery(this).val() == '') return; //qty empty, instead of removing item from cart, do nothing
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       jQuery("[name='update_cart']").prop("disabled", false);
       jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeout;

jQuery( function( $ ) {
$('.woocommerce').on('change', 'input.qty', function(){

    if ( timeout !== undefined ) {
        clearTimeout( timeout );
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
    }, 1000 ); // 1 second delay, half a second (500) seems comfortable too

   });
} );
```